# get users ip and check against block list?

Tags: php, mysql

when a user accesses my site im logging their ip address in the database, this is a precaution measure against fraud/spam.

im using this query to store the users ip

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, date, session_end) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), ADDDATE(), NULL);";
                mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

what i now want to do is have a script that when getting the ip, perform a check to see if this ip address exists in my table ptb_blocked_users and if it does, redirect the user to a blocked page.

could i do something like this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mytable");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ") {
     // row not found, show page..
} else {
    // block page
}
```

can someone show me how i would go about doing this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check banned table using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. If entries exists `header("Location:banned.php"); exit();`

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether ip exist in blocked database or not every time when you want to check it,

```
    $ip_addres=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $query="SELECT `ip` FROM `ptb_blocked_users` WHERE user_ip='$ip_addres'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('query failed');
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    //redirect to block page
    }
    else
    {
       //continue to script
    }
```

For IPv4 and IPv6 support use inet_pton() and inet_ntop(), these are availiable since PHP 5.1+ and mimic exactly the equivalent MySQL functions.

Otherwise just use ip2long() and long2ip().

The ip2long() and long2ip() functions should work

example:

```
var_dump(ip2long('209.85.227.147'));
var_dump(long2ip(3512066963));
```

using:

```
INSERT table(ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('192.168.0.1')); /*ip = 3232235521*/
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) As IPAddress FROM table; /*IPAddress = 192.168.0.1*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time analysing your data. IP addresses are not static, even within a session. Also, whenever you are working with IP addresses it's a lot more simple to treat them as numbers.

While it's a long way from being fool-proof:

```
CREATE TABLE block_list
(
   trunc_ip INT(4),
   added TIMESTAMP
   PRIMARY KEY (trunc_ip)
);
```

To block:

```
INSERT INTO block_list (trunc_ip)
VALUES (256*FLOOR(INET_ATON('" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')/256);
```

and to check for blocks:

```
SELECT 1 AS isblocked
FROM block_list
WHERE trunc_ip=(256*FLOOR(INET_ATON('" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')/256);
```

...allows you to black out a 8 bit subnet.

But there are better solutions including:

- requiring a verified email address

  - use openId with email service providers
    and/or
  - don't allow posting before the email is verified
- [Browser fingerprinting](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/im-currently-spending-significant.html)

Comment: what will be the value of `trunc_ip` i am bit confused

Comment: i want to know more on this please give me some reference

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_ip FROM ptb_blocked_users WHERE user_ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
 die(header("location: url"));
}
```